# APEX/ Chatter : Like a custom object record

Tags: apex, chatter

I've been implementing a chatter integration that enables to like a custom object record from apex.

I've created 1 custom object that represents **Articles**. Articles have Title, Description, Thumbnail and an access url.

I've enabled Chatter tracking feeds on these objects. And i would like to display **a like button** on each article listed from a lightning custom component. This like button should behave as the native Chatter Like  Button. So i should also be able to query the total likes on each article from Apex.

My code to implement the Custom Chatter Like button using Chatter Apex is as below :

```
ConnectApi.FeedElement feedElement = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement(Network.getNetworkId(), recordId, ConnectApi.FeedElementType.FeedItem, 'hello');
ConnectApi.ChatterLike chatterLike = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.likeFeedElement(null, feedElement.Id);
```

I'm not sure if i'm doing it right, specially the way i create the FeedElement using postFeedElement function.

Have you guys ever done this before? Could you please advice?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking because you're observing some error or non-expected behavior? If so, what is that error?

Comment: I'm not getting any error , but i'm just wondering if i'm creating the FeedElement as it should be. I'm suprised that to like a record, i've to post a feedElement with a  text parameter for example (ie: `Hello`)

Comment: Chatter likes apply to feed items, not records. The [ERD diagram](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_chatter.htm#!) might be useful (note that `AccountFeed` is holding the place of the generic `FeedItem` in the diagram).

Comment: Great!! So, instead of creating a feedElement, i should create a feedItem with type Record, am i right?

Comment: It might be helpful if you could add more narrative description (or even screenshots) to your question of what you want the outcome to look like.

Comment: I've have updated my post. Hope it will be more relevant!

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be looking for "follow" functionality. If so you should be able to execute DML operations on the `EntitySubscription` object directly, with no need for the ConnectAPI.

> ## [EntitySubscription](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_entitysubscription.htm)
>
> Represents a subscription for a user following a record or another user. This object is available in API version 34.0 and later.
>
> A user can subscribe to a record or to another user. Changes to the record and updates from the users are displayed in the Chatter feed on the user's home page, which is a useful way to stay up-to-date with other users and with changes made to records in Salesforce. Feeds are available in API version 18.0 and later.

If you look at other [Chatter Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/RelationshipsOfChatterObjects.htm), most others support DML as well. The only time I've found the ConnectAPI necessary is when you want to generate a FeedItem via Apex whose body contains an @mention.